# How can i change class of parent on click of checkbox and back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have made a responsive menu, everything works expect if you go on mobile.
I want the hamburger icon to scroll with the menu links, now if you scroll it just stays at the top, need to give the hamburgericon a position fixed on click and if it is clicked again return it to position absolute

i tried with javascript and sass, if it can be done with just pure css then its prerfect or else some javascript would be fine

the icon id is #menutoggle <= need to make this position: fixed on checkbox clicked

```css
#header {
  transition: all 300 ms ease;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 1em;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #header {
    padding: 1em 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #header {
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
#header a {
  color: white;
}
#header .header-inner {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 4em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #header .header-inner {
    max-width: 768px;
    height: 3em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .header-inner {
    height: 4em;
    padding: 0 1em 1em;
  }
}
#header .navbar {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .navbar {
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
#header .navbar .leaf {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#header .navbar .leaf:hover {
  background: red;
}
#header .navbar .logo {
  margin: 1em 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 360px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -38px;
  z-index: 5;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .navbar .logo {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(50%, 0px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    right: 50%;
    top: 5px;
    background: url("../images/crown.jpg.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #header .navbar .logo {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    right: 280px;
    top: -20px;
  }
}
#header .navbar .logo img {
  background-position: contain;
  width: 300px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .navbar .logo img {
    width: 135px;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #header .navbar .logo img {
    width: 225px;
  }
}
#header .navbar .menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .navbar .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
#header .navbar .menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#header .navbar .menu ul .video {
  margin-right: 345px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  #header .navbar .menu ul .video {
    margin-right: 260px;
  }
}
#header .navbar .menu li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 1.2em;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  #header .navbar .menu li {
    padding: 10px 1.2em;
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
}
#header .navbar .menu li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
#header .navbar nav {
  display: none;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  width: 100%;
  /* And let's fade it in from the left */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #header .navbar nav {
    display: block;
  }
}
#header .navbar nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}
#header .navbar nav a:hover {
  color: red;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  top: 16px;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 55px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 12;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle ul a {
  width: 100;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(215, 7, 120, 0.2);
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 3;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1), opacity 0.55s ease;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle input:checked ~ span {
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: red;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3) {
  margin-left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}
#header .navbar nav #menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1);
}
#header .navbar nav #menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
#header .navbar nav #menuToggle input:checked ~ ul {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.blok {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="home">
    <div id="header">
      <div class="header-inner">
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="" />
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/photo">Home</a></li>
              <li class="leaf video"><a title="" href="/video">About</a></li>
              <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/music">Menu</a></li>
              <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/forum">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <nav role="navigation">
            <div id="menuToggle">
              <input type="checkbox" />
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <ul id="menu">
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <hr class="line-menu">
                <a href="#">
                  <li>About</li>
                </a>
                <hr class="line-menu">
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Info</li>
                </a>
                <hr class="line-menu">
                <a href="#">
                  <li>Contact</li>
                </a>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end header-->
    <!--begin header-->
    <div class="blok"></div>
```

Comment: why can't you add the code here itself?

Comment: i don't understand? add the link itself how

Comment: Please add your code in the question. The rule is for a reason; link rot could mean this question will be useless for future visitors. Subverting the rule just makes it harder for people to help you, meaning you'll get no help and more downvotes.

Comment: aaah didn't  know let me update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code

```
 @media only screen and(max-width: 767px) {
     #header {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         width: 100% ;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @amirhanif, ? check the code pen, make the screen smalller.

Answer (score 0):

jq:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function() {
     $('#menutoggle').toggleClass('position-style');
});
```

css:

```
.position-style {
     position: fixed;
}
```

Hope this help you ;]

//edit https://jsfiddle.net/zfo5nzf3/
this code working, its adding '.position' class (where rule is position: fixed;) to #menutoggle according to your "the icon id is #menutoggle <= need to make this position: fixed on checkbox clicked".

Comment: do you have installed jquery librares?